# Interactive Grid- Automatic Row Processing (DML) : Character limitation in Code editor

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a requirement where 300 columns had to be processed. I am trying to achieve this using  IG automatic row processing (DML). When writing the code in the editor I get a error stating 'Value too long by 2015 characters'.

I suppose this is an Oracle Apex limitation. Can someone please share their views on this?

Comment: What is the length of the SQL statement for the IG?

Answer (score 0):

> When writing the code in the editor ...

I'd say that your problem isn't related to number of columns, but a large query which can't fit into "SQL Query" item of the Page Designer.

Which Apex version do you use? I can't tell for sure (as I don't know it), but my impression is that Apex up to version 4.2 had that item limited to `VARCHAR2(4000)` so - if your query is larger than that, it won't fit (such as in your case - query you wrote is 2015 characters longer than the maximum size the item allows). In 5.x version, you can put a whole lot of query into the item (as if it was modified to a `CLOB`).

Now, as you use Interactive Grid and it appeared in 5.x version, huh ... maybe what I wrote above isn't entirely true. Unfortunately, you can't switch to a query whose source is a function that returns query (such as in Classic Reports), as you could write a (stored) function and simply call it from Apex.

As you said that you used *automatic row processing*, did you put too much code somewhere in there?

On the other hand, I Googled a little bit, looking for limit of column numbers in the IG - couldn't find anything *official*, but someone complained (here, on StackOveflow) that they tried to create an IG with over 100 columns, and it didn't work.

So, yes - maybe you hit the limit, but I can't confirm it. Hopefully, someone who knows Apex better will be able to assist. Alternatively, consider asking the same question on OTN forums, as people who *designed* Apex answer questions there.